# Web analytics : unique visitor on a site page

Tags: web-analytics, sitepages

Anyone knows if it's possible to determine the number of unique visitors on a specific page of a SharePoint 2010 site? I've only been able to get the data for the entire site.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use javascript on page load and then store the data, for example, in a SharePoint List

Comment: @GintasK Like this one? http://www.hitwebcounter.com/ ;-P

Comment: @BennySkogberg no, I mean you can get the current user's details on page load and then log that data in a List, as the requirement is to count only unique visitors :)

Comment: @BennySkogberg assuming that we have to track unique SP Users. This also allows us to track who exactly visited the page and when :)

Comment: Thanks @GintasK. I like the way you think. Will look into your solution and see how I can make that happen. However my knowledge of Javascript is very limited. Any solutions that wouldn't involve coding?